# Does Laravel Valet have a un-park/unlink for all valet parked projects on a system?

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

Working on a computer with several old Laravel projects. It looks like they are all parked with Valet.

Valet is not working on new projects, I think because Valet is over extended.

Is there a way to 'mass' un-park and unlink all valet connections or do I have to uninstall and reinstall Valet?

Going through every folder individual and manually un-parking is unrealistic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet) doesn't have a command to forget all the registered working directories, you can manually do it by editing the `~/.valet/config.json` file and remove the registered directories from the `paths` array like the following:

```json
{
    "domain": "dev",
    "paths": [
        "/Users/whoami/.valet/Sites",
        "/Users/whoami/Sites/Test"
    ]
}
```

Alternatively, you can manually go to each of the registered Valet directories and forget them by running `valet forget`. However, this would be time-consuming especially when you have bulk registered directories with Valet.

Comment: it became `~/.config/valet/`

Comment: `C:\Users\ [username] \.config\valet` for Windows users

Answer (score 26):

[Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet#other-valet-commands) has `forget` command that removes parked directories to valet park list.

```
cd parked_directory
valet forget
```

Comment: `valet forget` doesn't remove all the parked directories. It just removes the current parked directory. So, why this should be the accepted answer when the question clearly says “unpark all valet registered directories”?

Comment: The questions says "Does Laravel Valet have a un-park/unlink for **all valet parked projects** on a system?" Valet parked projects, means all projects that are linked to valet. And additional, he asked to the description  if "there a way to 'mass' un-park and unlink all valet connections". I don't see it as a _"valet registered directories"_, what he says is "unlink all valet connections".

Answer (score 5):

```
valet links
```

will display all the links of the parked sites

```
valet unlink SITENAME
```

Comment: with this you need to unlink one by one. no ideal with many sites especially if you accidentally parked a whole directory. Peggy's answer is good one https://stackoverflow.com/a/54091249/6714319

Comment: @salam you're assuming an individual doesn't want to unlink just one or two sites out of all.  As stated in the documentation the link is for "if you want to serve a single site in a directory and not the entire directory."

Answer (score 2):

Try cd into the directory that you want to "un-park" and run

```
valet forget
```

Answer (score 1):

**To unlink the current working directory:**
valet unlink
**To unlink a specific project (directory):**
valet unlink my-project